# How to find the current azuer AD / office 365 user signed into a computer?

Tags: c#, angular, spring, spring-mvc, azure-active-directory

I am creating a web application that will authenticate users based on their azure ad / office 365 accounts. To log into their computers they use their ad / office 365 account and they will have access to the web app without signing in based on their AD access.

I have tried to follow tutorials to set up this type of authentication using spring and angular:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/azure/spring-framework/configure-spring-boot-starter-java-app-with-azure-active-directory?view=azure-java-stable

Almost all of these guides or docs require setting up the app on the azure ad site, which produces a client id, key, and tenant id for the web application, which can be used with spring security to authenticate users.

I do not have access / permission to create a app registration, but I still need to get the ad userId of the user attempting to access my web application.

There is an existing web application created using asp.net core and angular which accomplishes what I am trying to achieve in java spring. I have tried to understand how it authenticates users but I am still stumped.

In the .net core project a controller makes a call to HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Header to grab the userId of the user logged into their office 365 / ad account. This call is made in a controller class.

I cannot post more of the c# code so it will probably be hard to help me understand how it works in asp.net, but if there is any way to achieve what I described above in Java Spring I would love to know.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to achieve this without registering your application in these users AAD tenant. That's part of establishing trust between your app and the authority (AAD) which does the work of authenticating users. By registering your app id and reply url(s) you tell AAD that it's OK for it to send you user's info.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I hope I can get access to register the app then so that I can actually implement proper authentication.